# Offsite backup from a timemachine capsule

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, remote-backup, timemachine, offsite

How can I create a (secondary) backup to a offsite location of a timemachine backup residing on a apple timecapsule?

Possible destinations are Amazon S3, Mosso Cloud Files, Generic SSH/SCP servers, ...

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that time machine uses heavily the features of the underlying mac file system HFS+, looking into [RDiff](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/non-gnu/rdiff-backup/) would make sense. RDiff can be used to sync folder via networks and supports specific mac features. Thus it maybe can be used maybe to even sync a timemachine backup to the remote server.
The remote server needs a ssh-login and has to have a POSIX file system.